# Multiprocessing, share pool between different Python instances

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, joblib

I have a parallel version of an algorithm that uses the `multiprocessing` and `joblib` Python packages.

**Example:**

```
import multiprocessing
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def algorithm(files_list):
    # do stuff to files

# ... some setup code

num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

n_per_job = int(num_files / num_cores) + 1

results = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(algorithm)(files[i*n_per_job:min((i+1)*n_per_job, num_files)]) for i in range(num_cores))

# ... do something with results
```

Now the problem comes when, in some situations, I might have **multiple instances** of this script running **at the same time**, making the number of processes running at the same time on the CPU really big with too many context switches.

Is there a way to **limit** the number of processes that multiprocessor can spawn **globally**, for multiple instances? Is there a way to make a **global Pool**?

P.S.: I am using the code in Unix machines if you need to know.

Comment: Do you need limit the master threads in your environment or master and sub threads together? Because master thread can generate new threads hierarchically within same master thread (sub process limitation). This kind of limitation may cause your process to stuck in a situation like, you set 64 threads as your master limit, then execute your code with 100 input, compiler will start 64 threads simultaneously and if any of of your first level process tries to start a new thread compiler will pause your current thread, which eventually make a dead-lock in your code.

Comment: No, just the master threads (processes). In my case they do not spawn sub threads or processes. And in each situation I can guarantee that the number of instances and the number of processes spawned is finite and limited.